# WP Contact Form 7 JavaScript copy fields

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am building a complex mortgage calculator with input fields. I created a cf7 form which is the plugin they use for all their other forms to interface with the db plugin and capture the data. I have hidden fields in cf7 with the same ids and I'm trying to copy the data from the iframe excel converted form to the cf7 form when the field is on blur using jQuery.  I have the same ids for each correlated field and was hoping to do a for each copy or clone on the fields that are hidden within cf7.

I'm very new to js and I've cobbled together most of what I need from other posts, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. cf7 has on submit and on mail ok hooks, but those aren't quite going to do it. I tried on submit also, but for some reason they all came over on page load only and the top two of four had wrong numbers. I'm not certain if it's possible to get this to work as is without hooking into the plugin, or if javascript will transfer the text without hooking in and I just have it wrong. I could really use some help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clonetxt() {
    $("input").each(function() {
      if (type.hidden == "true") {
        $("id", parent.document.body) .blur();
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

Originally I tried this on submit with the aria-required flag because I wanted to be able to see what was going on before I hid these fields and the fields that weren't going to pull from the other form I had set to required.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clonetxt() {
    $("input").each(function() {
      if (type.aria-required !== "true") {
        $("id", parent.document.body);
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a job for the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin.  It has the ability to [pre-fill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPPD5VBF78w) a form with certain values, as well as a handy [dynamic dropdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8) field which you can either populate from your CMS data or programmatically with filters.